# 2 issues with Bootstrap 4 Tooltip. 1st - Displayed when button clicked, 2nd - Displaying for disabled elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I am using Bootstrap 4 and I have an issue with my`tooltip`.

I load the following in my `index.html`:

```
$('body').tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', delay: { show: 550, hide: 0 } });
```

But when I click I button, the `tooltip` displays and remains on the page I am on.

Using the `index` code above, I click a menu option and taken to the page using:

```
$('#adminCreateInvoiceLink').on('click', function () {
    $('#mainPanel').load('components/specificPagesAdministrator/createInvoices/createInvoices.html');
})
```

If I hover on the button, my `tooltip` displays then hides

```
<button id="clearButton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" aria-hidden="true" title="Click to clear the date"
class="btn roundButton d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center alert-warning" disabled>
    <i class="fas fa-times" style="font-size: medium"></i>
</button>
```

**Page load**

[image]

**After 'X' click**

[image]

The only code I got for the 'X' click is the following

```
$('#clearButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#createInvoiceDateField').val('')
    $('#createInvoiceSubmitButton, #clearButton').prop('disabled', true);
})
```

This isn't the only page is happening on though, and I don't want to have to keep adding `script` if it can be helped also having an issue where my `tooltip` is also displaying for `disabled` elements and shouldn't be as it displays but isn't styled in black.

Answer (score 1):

With the code you provided, your button does not show the tooltip on click, but with a delay of 500ms on hover. if you want to display the tooltip immediately on hover, remove the `delay: { show: 550, hide: 0 }` part.

To remove the disabled buttons from your selection add `:not([disabled])` to your selector.

```js
$('body').tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]:not([disabled])'});

$('#clearButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#clearButton').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="clearButton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="I have a tooltip"
class="btn btn-success"> I have a tooltip</button>
<button id="clearButton" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-danger" disabled data-title="no title">
  I don't have a tooltip
</button>
```

EDIT:

I just realized you meant the default tooltips that you want to disable. You can use the `data-title` for your tooltips, so that the elements with a disable attribute dont show a default tooltip provided by the title attribute.

Furthermore: The disabled attribute disables all mouse events for the element. Meaning that you have to manually close the tooltip because your mouseout event will not get fired on your disabled button

Answer (score 0):

Fix to stop `tooltip` displaying was to replace `title` with `data-title`

The fix to hide the `tooltip` when a `button` is clicked across the whole site was to add the following in my `index.html`

```
$('body').delegate('button', 'click', function () {
    $('body').tooltip('hide');
});
```

Comment: Just like my edit said an hour ago ;) Glad you found it.